# Integrate Google reCAPTCHA into Contact Form plugin

Tags: form, emails, plugin-contactform

So I just recently plugged in [pixelandtonic/ContactForm plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) into my website and I realized I got about 3 spam emails straight into my inbox on the first day it was up.

Is there a way to integrate the simple "one click" google Recaptcha into this form? Or is there any other/better solution than the Honeypot?

Thanks for the help!

---- **EDIT** -----
Ever since I've installed the [Spam Guard](https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.spamguard) Plugin, I haven't received anymore spam! This is a must with Pixel's Contact form plugin.

Answer (score 3):

There are several [anti-SPAM](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/?q=spam&) form plugins available for Craft that should work for you (including a Google reCAPTCHA one).

Comment: Indeed! Spam Guard plugin did the trick! thanks https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.spamguard

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue and fixed it by using Craft reCaptcha plugin. See: https://github.com/aberkie/craft-recaptcha

Comment: sean, did you get this to work out-of-the-box? Craft 2 site?

Comment: If I understand you correctly and you are also using Contact form plugin, I submitted a PR to the above repo to add support: https://github.com/aberkie/craft-recaptcha/pull/13